# Can't update HAXM: "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 6.2.1)" failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 on Windows 10. I tried to update the Intel Emulator Accelerator (HAXM) using the SDK Manager but it does not work, I get the following message:

```
To install:
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)
Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 6.2.1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_r6_2_1.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer): C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation01\android\repository\extras\intel\haxm-windows_r6_2_1.zip (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 6.2.1)" failed.
Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 6.2.1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_r6_2_1.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer): C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation01\haxm-windows_r6_2_1.zip (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable).
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 6.2.1)" failed.
Failed packages:
- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)
```

I even manually downloaded the file https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_r6_2_1.zip then unzipped it and executed the file **silent_install.bat** as administrator. But Android Studio is still displaying 6.2.0 as the installed version. Is there a way to update HAXM?

Comment: Strange fact: I just discovered that the manual installation actually worked somehow. I went to **Programs and Functionalities** in the **Control Panel**, and there the **Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager** installed version is 6.2.1! But Android Studio is still displaying 6.2.0, even after restarting it

Comment: Following your comment, I saw that a previous version (6.0.something) was installed. I've uninstalled it using the Windows Control Panel and installed the new one (6.2.1) with AS. It works! Thx

Comment: I am too facing the same problem ,can anyone have the solution ,please suggest ..

Answer (score 4):

**Uninstall** Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager in **Control Panel** and try it again..

Comment: this assumes you still have it in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\intel\HAXM\6.2.1\silent\ otherwise where to download the old version?

Comment: Idk why I didn't even think of this, but yup, this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

To whom it may concern, I have recently come across this problem and found [this article by tektutorialshub](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/android-studio/haxm-installation-failed-install-intel-haxm-in-windows/#what-is-intel-haxm) very useful. I am quoting a part of the article as it is relevant:

> What is Intel HAXM?
>
> The HAXM stands for Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager. It is a cross-platform hardware-assisted virtualization engine (hypervisor), The Android Emulator use HAXM in intel platforms to speedup & improve performance
>
> Why does HAXM Installation fail?
>
> The Android Studio Installs Intel HAXM when you install Android Studio. But you may get the HAXM Installation Failed message because of the following reasons:
>
> - Android emulator is already running
> - The processor is not Intel-based
> - Unsupported OS
> - Hyper-V Manager must be disabled
> - Virtualization must be enabled in Bios (VT-x)
> - The PC must support Virtualisation
> - Antivirus (Avast) may interfere with HAXM Installation

In my case, I used an [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Micro_Devices) processor, so I found this article by Android developers Google blog: [Android Emulator - AMD Processor & Hyper-V Support](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have currently faced the same issue in Android Studio. I searched all the answers on the web, but nothing worked for me.

After that, I just deleted my Android SDK and installed with the new one. It solves the problem like a charm. You can get the SDK from there official website: *[Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)*.

Answer (score 0):

Open a cmd or PowerShell window as administrator.

Then enter the command

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Restart your PC.

Answer (score -2):

In order to successfully install or update HAXM on Windows 10 to run Android Emulator, you need to enable Intel [VT-x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_(VT-x)).
To enable Intel VT-x, go to Windows BIOS to enable it.

This is not only for running the Android emulator. This problem is faced when running a [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_virtualization) in your Windows as well.

Comment: We are talking about *updating* HAXM. It would not have been possible to install it in the first place if the virtualization option was not enabled.